# pass viewModel object from controller to view in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following method in controller

```
public ActionResult Categorized() 
{ 
    var x=new Test.Models.MobileClass(); 
    return View(x);
}
```

x object contains methods that return xmldocument data

how can I pass this object to view to access methods and  display data from  xmldocument in browser

I can display it element element by using the following code

```
document.writeln("@Model.getxml().ChildNodes.Count");
```

but I want to use for loop displaying the contents of object and the following code didn't work in javascript

```
var size=parseInt("@Model.Getxml().ChildNodes.Count");
for  (var i=0; i<size; i++)

{

    document.writeln("@Model.Getxml().ChildNodes[i].InnerText");

 }
```

can you help me please

Comment: If the code in your view has to know specific details about the structure of an XML document, you need a better ViewModel.

Comment: javascript is client side, in the browser, the view and the Model is server side, you generate html at the server side and the browser receives that html

Comment: You already asked this question once and the exact same answers still apply: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16351921/1043198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your view should not be calling Getxml and mucking about with the XML DOM. It's the job of the controller to present the view with "ready to render" data. That's what a ViewModel is for.

```
public ActionResult Categorized() 
{ 
    var foo = new Test.Models.MobileClass(); 
    var xml = foo.Getxml();
    var viewData = xml.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => x.InnerText);
    return View(viewData);
}
```

Now we're passing an `IEnumerable<string>` to the view, containing just the values we want to render.

In the view, you should not be using javascript to render your data to HTML - use the view to render your data to HTML - the Razor template engine is really good at that! Something like...

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript will fail, since the variable i will be evaluated on the server side and doesn't exist then.
Use a foreach in the view, with razor:

```
@foreach(var child in Model.Getxml().ChildNodes)
{
    child.InnerText
}
```